# Outlook 2007 script to save attachments into a specific folder based on subject line

Tags: email, script, microsoft-outlook-2007, attachments

I'm trying to build a client-side script in Outlook 2007 that processes incoming email and attachments.  Emails that need this special treatment will have a tag “XYZ*” followed by a single word subject say, “SUBJECT”.  The script should then

Look for a folder called “SUBJECT” located on say, the P:\ drive
If folder does not already exist, then create a new folder called “SUBJECT”
Save all attachments in the email into the folder “SUBJECT”

I'm told this can be done but have no idea how unfortunately (not a programmer).

Comment: In case the deleted answer is not expanded upon and undeleted, the link provided was to a macro on [this page](http://www.pixelchef.net/content/rule-autosave-attachment-outlook).

Comment: Duplicated here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15336957/vba-in-outlook-2007-algo-implemenation-to-save-attachments-to-a-folder-based-o